# Replace integers in a string with Array values to correspond the order

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, loops

I have string which I want to replace the integers (numbers) with my array value to be in a correspondence order, the string can have different mathematical signs depending oh how the user captured the data. I can have a string and an array like:

```
var myArray = [
    "John",
    "London", 
    "March", 
    "Year 2017", 
    "My Age", 
    "We will meet", 
    "Next year", 
    "Year end"];

var testString = "234 == 123 AND 346 == 378 OR 123 >= 236 AND 124 != 478";
```

I am expecting the result to be a string like this:

```
"John == London AND March == Year 2017 OR My Age >= We will meet AND Next year != Year end"
```

See the code below and help where Im going wrong.

```
var myArray = ["John", "London", "March", "Year 2017", "My Age", "We will meet", "Next year", "Year end"];
var testString = "234 == 123 AND 346 == 378 OR 123 >= 236 AND 124 != 478";

var partsA = testString.split(" AND ");
console.log("A:", partsA);
var partsB = [];
var newString = "";
$.each(partsA, function(k, v) {
    partsB = v.split(" == ");
    console.log("B-1:", partsB);
    if (!isNaN(partsB[0])) {
        partsB[0] = myArray[parseInt(partsB[0])];
    }
    if (!isNaN(partsB[1])) {
        partsB[1] = myArray[parseInt(partsB[1])];
    }
    console.log("B-2:", partsB);
    partsA[k] = partsB.join(" == ");
});
newString = partsA.join(" AND ");
console.log("S:", newString);
$("#newstring").text(newString);
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the code you have now? Error messages? Wrong output? What do the console.log calls print and what did you expect them  to print?

Comment: @JJJ the output comes like these ==  AND  ==  OR   >=   AND   !=

Comment: Can you format your code? It is almost impossible to read right now!

Comment: @gurvinder372 edited the code

Comment: What is the expected output? What are these numbers?!

Comment: @chsdk in this case the expected output would be like these John == London AND March == Year 2017 OR My Age >= We will meet AND Next year != Year end. The numbers are array element ID's which I get from the db. exec the id's only and pass them on another method to get the description which is the array I have there.

Comment: @YouNeverKnow Can you show this method, or will be reading directly from the array?!

Comment: @chsdk yes reading from the array provided directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace all the `numbers` with their respective `strings` from the `myArray` array, taking the `string` with the same `index`, you can do the following:

```
var matches = testString.match(/\d+/g);
var result = testString;
matches.forEach(function(str, index) {
  result = result.replace(str, myArray[index]);
});
```

- Get all the numbers into a `matches` array, using `.match(/\d+/)`.
- Then loop over this array of matches and replace each number with its
  matching `string` from your `myArray`variable.

It will give you the following result:

> John == London AND March == Year 2017 OR My Age >= We will meet AND Next year != Year end

**Demo:**

```js
var myArray = ["John", "London", "March", "Year 2017", "My Age", "We will meet", "Next year", "Year end"];
var testString = "234 == 123 AND 346 == 378 OR 123 >= 236 AND 124 != 478";

var matches = testString.match(/\d+/g);
var result = testString;
matches.forEach(function(str, index) {
  result = result.replace(str, myArray[index]);
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks a lot thats what I was looking for. Great response